# MVC 3 Complex Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've just got myself into a little mess and am having trouble thinking myself out of it.  I have the following domain model (reduced for brevity):

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionGroup> QuestionGroups { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Headings { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

Now, when I'm rendering my `Questionnaire` in my view I'm using **EditorTemplates** for each `QuestionGroup` and `Question`. When rendering my `Question` I'm looking at the `Type` property (which is something like RadioButtonList or TextArea) and for each `Heading` (which is a comma separated string).  So for example, let's say we have a `Question` initialised like so:

```
var question = new Question() {
    Text = "My Question Text",
    Type = "RadioButtonList",
    Headings = "Very Difficult,2,3,4,Very Easy"
};
```

Then we would end up with this:

[image]

Which is produced in my **EditorTemplate** like so:

```
@foreach (var heading in Model.Headings.Split(','))
{
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>@heading</strong>
            @Html.RadioButton(Model.Id.ToString(), heading)
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

The markup for this looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>Very Difficult</strong>
            <input id="group_question_1" name="group.question.1" type="radio" value="Very Difficult" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>2</strong>
            <input id="group_question_1" name="group.question.1" type="radio" value="2" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>3</strong>
            <input id="group_question_1" name="group.question.1" type="radio" value="3" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>4</strong>
            <input id="group_question_1" name="group.question.1" type="radio" value="4" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <strong>Very Easy</strong>
            <input id="group_question_1" name="group.question.1" type="radio" value="Very Easy" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have produced a **Custom Model Binder** but this is where I'm a little stuck. My actual questions are:

1. How do I persist the selected value based on my domain model in the view?
2. Am I even using the correct approach for something like this, or am I way off?

I must admit, I'm still very much in the learning stage of MVC so I could be a bit blind-sided from my own attempt. Any help always appreciated!

Comment: Don't confuse the model you use to display the view and the model used to get the results - these _can_ (and probably _should_ be different). See [The Three Models of ASP.NET MVC Apps](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/) by Dino Esposito.

Comment: @Oded: Interesting, I did consider using a view model as a proxy but was attempting to keep my code minimal by having my presentation layer work directly with the domain model - I agree this is the exception rather than rule, but it's worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this using a custom model binder as mentioned in another question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318484/961328

Answer (score 1):

You should have a viewmodel between your db entities and view. If you wish to add for ex. validation it will get pretty messy to use validation attributes on your db classes.
In the long run viewmodels will save you time.